# swi-prolog time/1 to file

Tags: performance, runtime, swi-prolog

Is it possible to write the results of time/1 to file or have them returned as a variable to automate the runtime comparison?

Or is there another predicate to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this is to use the statistics/2 predicate.

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=statistics%2F2